# How can I extract a file zip into a directory created before by code (PHP)?

Tags: php, unzip

I want to extract a file zip into a directory created before by code using PHP but it doesn't work. I think that it's a problem of permissions because if I create that folder manually it work, instad if I create it from my script it doesn't work!

```
....
$filename = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
$source = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];
$name = explode(".", $filename);
$target_path = "Apps\\" . $username . "\\" . $name[0]; 

if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path))
{       
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $x = $zip->open($target_path);
    if ($x === true)
    {
       $zip->extractTo("Apps\\".$username); <- ERROR ON THIS LINE
       $zip->close();
    }
 ....
```

This is the error:(Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): No such file or directory)

How can I resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: check your file path where you want to extract

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

Comment: My guess is the ziparchive needs a full path. If the open works the path should exist. However you are using a relative path. Try something like `__DIR__."Apps\\".$username`

Comment: I don't think that it's a problem of path because if I write that.. $zip->extractTo("Apps\folderCreatedManually"); instead of $zip->extractTo("Apps\\".$username); it work!

Comment: yes this is path problem and error message also tell path issue

Comment: $zip->extractTo("Apps\".$username); 
if user name folder exit then use this code

Comment: That should not be the way it goes, you are now escaping the double quotes and creating a parse error. Btw to avoid all that nonsense you can also use forward slashes that don't need escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolve it do that:

```
$filename = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
$source = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];

$name = explode(".", $filename);
$target_path = "Apps/" . $username . "/" . $name[0]. "." .$name[1];    

if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path))
{       
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $x = $zip->open($target_path);
    if ($x === true)
    {
        $zip->extractTo("Apps/" . $username . "/");
        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

It was a problem of $target_path because it need the extension ($name[1])

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

this is your path problem so update your path then it will work perfectly and this is demo code which help you to upload zip file and extract this zip in same file with zip folder also.

```
<?php
function rmdir_recursive($dir) {
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
        if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) continue;
        if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) rmdir_recursive("$dir/$file");
        else unlink("$dir/$file");
    }

    rmdir($dir);
}

if(!empty($_FILES["file_name"]["name"])) {
    $filename = $_FILES["file_name"]["name"];
    $source = $_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["file_name"]["type"];

    $name = explode(".", $filename);
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
    foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
        if($mime_type == $type) {
            $okay = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
    if(!$continue) {
        $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
    }

    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';  
    $filenoext = basename ($filename, '.zip');
    $filenoext = basename ($filenoext, '.ZIP');

    $targetdir = $path . $filenoext; 
    $targetzip = $path . $filename; 
    if (is_dir($targetdir))  rmdir_recursive ( $targetdir);

    mkdir($targetdir, 0777);

    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $targetzip)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open($targetzip);
        if ($x === true) {
            $zip->extractTo($targetdir.'/');
            $zip->close();

            unlink($targetzip);
        }
        $message = "Your file is uploaded and unpacked.";
    } else {
        $message = "There is a problem to upload.";
    }
}

?>

<?php if(isset($message)) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <label>Upload a zip file to upload: <input type="file" name="file_name" /></label>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

hope it will help you and others

Comment: Why have you put $target_path between ''? that return false and so it never enter in the if positive condition.. if I delete ' ' around $target_path it return true but when it do  $zip->extractTo('Apps/'.$username); the usual error appears.

Comment: target path is your file path name , in bellow example check it

Comment: ok, it work! but it copy only the zip archive without extension in the destination folder without extract it..

Comment: o you mean  just copy folder but not extract?

Comment: so your extract not work, move_uploaded_file just work

Comment: if I use xxx.zip, into Apps/userFolder there is a file without extension called xxx

Comment: if not solved then give me your email id , i will send code for your test